# Apache and iis on same server and same port

Tags: java, .net, apache, iis

I have a web application built using java and .net and using oracle database. My problem is that I want to host this application and in order to do this I have to run apache and iis on the same server and same port. Is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible. How could you be using both .net and java??

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these options:

1. Set a second IP on your network interface and set your Java Server
   (tomcat, jboss, etc) and IIS to these IPs (each server each IP).
2. Or you can try to configure your IIS server as a reverse proxy to your java  server. You will do something like this:
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/integrating-jira-applications-with-iis-861253891.html). In this setting your tomcat (or whatever java server you are running) will run on a diferent port then your IIS and can share the same IP address.